# MS Word for Mac (latest version) - resetting normal.dotm

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, templates

I want to reset the normal.dotm template on a Mac with the latest version of MS Word (15.x.x).

I found instructions on doing this on Windows [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-can-i-restore-normaldotm-to-a-virgin-state/99d1f145-8b55-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5).

What's the equivalent for Mac Word?

Rationale for doing this is to try to avoid the problem addressed in [this question.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230091/headings-and-numbering-glitches-in-ms-word-for-mac-2015-version-15-18/237945)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this thread in [Apple Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/where-are-microsoft-office-for-mac-my-templates-stored), the folder's location has changed for Office for Mac 2016. It's now located in

`~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Templates`

For Office for Mac 2011 or if you upgraded from this edition to 2016, browse to this location

`~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/User Templates/My Templates`

In Windows, I can delete the file `normal.dotm` to reset it. So you should try doing so in your Mac. You need first to close Word before deleting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - are you aware of any potential risk attached to deleting normal.dotm before I try that out?

Comment: `normal.dotm` is built into Word's code so if Word didn't find it, it'll recreate it from scratch with default settings. You don't need to delete it if you are not convinced; just move (not 'copy') the file to another safe folder if things have gone awry so you can restore it back.

Comment: Any idea _how long_ Word takes to do this?

I renamed the normal.dotm file and opened Word, tried creating a new doc and saving it, restarting the Mac etc. but so far... no new normal.dotm file!

Comment: If you managed to get a new document in Word then Word recreated `normal.dotm` successfully. The new template is probably hidden or in another directory. Try finding a folder called `Templates` (not `User Templates`, or `My Templates`) somewhere within `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft`.

Answer (score 3):

For those who wind up here looking for how to find the Normal.dotm file on a Mac, (OSX 10.13.3 and Word v16.10, US English) I found it here:

```
cd ~/Library/Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User\ Content.localized/Templates.localized/
rm Normal.dotm
rm normal.dotm.bak
```

And as the instructions here say, deleting or moving the corrupted Normal.dotm fixes the problem, by auto-creating a new template when Word next runs.